# Odd sf::st_crop() behaviour

Tags: r, r-sf

I want to crop one `sf` object by another, which I can do with `sf::st_crop()` or `sf::st_intersection()`. However, the resulting cropped object, doesn't match the object it was cropped by (see below reprex). Instead it looks like the crop happened on the top left corner and the bottom right. How do I get it to actually clip to the outline of `poly1`?

```
library(sf); library(rnaturalearth)
# polygon to clip by
poly1 <- matrix(c(-113, 23.5, 
                  -113, -23.5, 
                  -34, -23.5, 
                  -34, 23.5, 
                  -113, 23.5),
                byrow=T, ncol=2) %>%
    list() %>%
    st_polygon() %>% 
    st_sfc(., crs = "epsg:4326")

countries <- ne_countries(continent = c("South America", "North America"), 
                          returnclass = "sf") %>%
    st_transform(., crs="epsg:4326")

plot(countries$geometry)
plot(poly1, add=T, border = "red")

cr1 <- st_crop(countries, poly1)
plot(cr1$geometry, add=T, col="red")

# intersection does the same
cr2 <- st_intersection(countries, poly1)
plot(cr2, add=T, col="green")
```

[image]

EDIT: it turns out that if I revert to a previous version of R (which also has different package versions attached), this error goes away.

Session info where issue arises:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8.1 x64 (build 9600)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                            LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] rnaturalearth_0.1.0 sf_1.0-0           

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.7         magrittr_2.0.1     units_0.7-2        tidyselect_1.1.1   lattice_0.20-44    R6_2.5.1           rlang_0.4.11      
 [8] fansi_0.5.0        s2_1.0.6           dplyr_1.0.7        wk_0.4.1           tools_4.1.0        grid_4.1.0         KernSmooth_2.23-20
[15] utf8_1.2.2         e1071_1.7-7        DBI_1.1.1          rgeos_0.5-5        ellipsis_0.3.2     class_7.3-19       assertthat_0.2.1  
[22] tibble_3.1.4       lifecycle_1.0.0    crayon_1.4.1       purrr_0.3.4        vctrs_0.3.8        glue_1.4.2         sp_1.4-5          
[29] proxy_0.4-26       compiler_4.1.0     pillar_1.6.2       generics_0.1.0     classInt_0.4-3     pkgconfig_2.0.3
```

Session info where it doesn't:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8.1 x64 (build 9600)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                            LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] rnaturalearth_0.1.0 sf_0.9-7           

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.6         pillar_1.4.6       compiler_3.6.3     plyr_1.8.6         class_7.3-15       tools_3.6.3        lifecycle_0.2.0   
 [8] tibble_3.0.4       gtable_0.3.0       lattice_0.20-41    pkgconfig_2.0.3    rlang_0.4.10       DBI_1.1.1          rstudioapi_0.11   
[15] yaml_2.2.1         e1071_1.7-4        dplyr_1.0.0        stringr_1.4.0      rgeos_0.5-2        generics_0.1.0     vctrs_0.3.4       
[22] classInt_0.4-3     grid_3.6.3         tidyselect_1.1.0   glue_1.4.2         ggnewscale_0.4.3   R6_2.4.1           sp_1.4-5          
[29] purrr_0.3.4        reshape2_1.4.4     ggplot2_3.3.2.9000 magrittr_2.0.1     scales_1.1.1       ellipsis_0.3.1     units_0.6-7       
[36] rsconnect_0.8.16   colorspace_1.4-1   KernSmooth_2.23-16 stringi_1.5.3      munsell_0.5.0      crayon_1.3.4
```

Comment: When I run your code I get a different output: on my end the cropped shapes are entirely within the red rectangle. (so e.g. Florida isn't red when I run it.) It's the same for both `cr1` and `cr2`.

Comment: Weird.. I've been running this in R 4.1.0 (added session info). I've just been back and tried running in 3.6.3 and it turns out in that version I don't get this error! I'd still like to establish what is going wrong running it in 4.1.0 and try to resolve it

Comment: ..on reflection much more likely to owe to the version of `sf` than anything else.. will look into this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with `sf_1.0-0` following the move to using `s2`. It's fixed by running `sf_use_s2(FALSE)` at the start of the script.